# Line and column bar is disappeared in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

That bar is disappeared. I am not sure what should I call that bar but it's disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Try zooming out with `Cmd minus`. It may be really small and hard to read but it should work. In my case, there were too many things on the status bar. Zooming out revealed it.

Comment: That did it, thanks! 

Also, there was too much stuff on my status bar now. I told it to hide the AWS Toolkit info and now I can see everything without zooming out.

Answer (score 0):

It's the status bar, you need to do:

```
View > Appearance > Show Status Bar
```

Comment: No in my VSCode.  Status bar is visible, but line number column number are not visible

Comment: @MubinIcyer I have the same problem, but only on some languages in vscode.